# put photo on the text in xml in android

Tags: android

I want to put photo on the text but I can not do it and puted text on the photo
Is it possible and if the answer is yes, what should I do?

These are pictures to understand the story better one:[image]

[image]
 this is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aval6.html");
  //        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
  //        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);

}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

and xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backmatn1" >

  <android.webkit.WebView
  android:id="@+id/webView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

</android.webkit.WebView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to achieve second one?

Comment: I am unsure exactly what you mean. However, you can use frame layout to achieve the effect you are looking for. Have a look at this tutorial which I found helpful when learning about frame layouts. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Comment: share your aval6.html